# Polarisation Identity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be an unitary vector space.

$$\frac{\ 1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^4 i^n||u+i^nv||^2 = \overline{\langle u, v \rangle}$$

I need to proof this formula. It looks very similar to the polarization formula for hermitian sesquilinear forms, is it the same?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731612/prove-let-v-be-a-unitary-vector-space#comment7671602_3731612

Comment: thanks, I'm sorry I haven't seen this until now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming linearity in the inner product's second argument (the physicist's convention),$$\Vert u+i^nv\Vert=\langle u+i^nv,\,u+i^nv\rangle=\Vert u\Vert^2+\Vert v\Vert^2+i^{-n}\langle v,\,u\rangle+i^n\langle u,\,v\rangle,$$so$$i^n\Vert u+i^nv\Vert=i^n(\Vert u\Vert^2+\Vert v\Vert^2)+\langle v,\,u\rangle+(-1)^n\langle u,\,v\rangle.$$Summing over $n$ gets rid of $i^n$ factors, as well as $(-1)^n$ factors, leaving $4\langle v,\,u\rangle$ as claimed.